# How to attach to working container with Docker.DotNet (NET CORE)

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I try to use https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet for control docker container.
One of important future to working with running container is attaching to running container with one command. Or with /bin/bash if we can attach interactively. So, this is command:

```
# sudo docker exec -it 7dde487b4424 bash
# sudo docker exec -it 7dde487b4424 pwd
```

Unfortunately, I can not found this command Docker.DotNet, some functions has similar name, but has no parameters like "bash command"

```
Public Interface IContainerOperations
    Function ListContainersAsync(parameters As ContainersListParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of IList(Of ContainerListResponse))
    Function ExtractArchiveToContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerPathStatParameters, stream As Stream, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function GetArchiveFromContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As GetArchiveFromContainerParameters, statOnly As Boolean, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of GetArchiveFromContainerResponse)
    Function RemoveContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerRemoveParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function WaitContainerAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of ContainerWaitResponse)
    Function AttachContainerAsync(id As String, tty As Boolean, parameters As ContainerAttachParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of MultiplexedStream)
    Function UnpauseContainerAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function PauseContainerAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function RenameContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerRenameParameters, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Function KillContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerKillParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function RestartContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerRestartParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function StopContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerStopParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Function StartContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerStartParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Function ResizeContainerTtyAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerResizeParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function GetContainerStatsAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerStatsParameters, progress As IProgress(Of ContainerStatsResponse), Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    <Obsolete("Use 'Task GetContainerStatsAsync(string id, ContainerStatsParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<JSONMessage> progress)'")>
    Function GetContainerStatsAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerStatsParameters, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Stream)
    Function ExportContainerAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of Stream)
    Function InspectChangesAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of IList(Of ContainerFileSystemChangeResponse))
    Function GetContainerLogsAsync(id As String, tty As Boolean, parameters As ContainerLogsParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of MultiplexedStream)
    Function GetContainerLogsAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerLogsParameters, cancellationToken As CancellationToken, progress As IProgress(Of String)) As Task
    <Obsolete("The stream returned by this method won't be demultiplexed properly if the container was created without a TTY. Use GetContainerLogsAsync(string, bool, ContainerLogsParameters, CancellationToken) instead")>
    Function GetContainerLogsAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerLogsParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of Stream)
    Function ListProcessesAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerListProcessesParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of ContainerProcessesResponse)
    Function InspectContainerAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of ContainerInspectResponse)
    Function CreateContainerAsync(parameters As CreateContainerParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of CreateContainerResponse)
    Function PruneContainersAsync(Optional parameters As ContainersPruneParameters = Nothing, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of ContainersPruneResponse)
    Function UpdateContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerUpdateParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of ContainerUpdateResponse)
End Interface
```

UPD: According to notes @kthompso

If we can see to exec interface

```
Public Interface IExecOperations
    Function ExecCreateContainerAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerExecCreateParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of ContainerExecCreateResponse)
    Function StartContainerExecAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function StartAndAttachContainerExecAsync(id As String, tty As Boolean, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of MultiplexedStream)
    Function StartWithConfigContainerExecAsync(id As String, eConfig As ContainerExecStartParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of MultiplexedStream)
    Function ResizeContainerExecTtyAsync(id As String, parameters As ContainerResizeParameters, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task
    Function InspectContainerExecAsync(id As String, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task(Of ContainerExecInspectResponse)
End Interface
```

We can see only two methods with CMD parameters - ExecCreateContainerAsync and StartWithConfigContainerExecAsync.

I try to use it

```
            AttachToContainer(DockerHub, ContainerId, CMD, LogCtsSrc.Token)
            ReadContainerLog(DockerHub, ContainerId, Sub(X) Console.WriteLine(X), LogCtsSrc.Token)

            Function AttachToContainer(DockerHub As DockerClient, ContainerID As String, Cmd As IList(Of String), ExecCts As CancellationToken) As Task(Of ContainerExecCreateResponse)
                Dim ExecTask As Task(Of ContainerExecCreateResponse) = DockerHub.Exec.ExecCreateContainerAsync(ContainerID, New ContainerExecCreateParameters With {
                                 .AttachStdin = False,
                                 .AttachStderr = True,
                                 .AttachStdout = True,
                                 .Tty = False,
                                 .Cmd = Cmd
                                },
                                ExecCts)
                 Return ExecTask
             End Function
```

And receive nothing, only old part of container log instead response of my commands in CMD.

[image]

It's not looks as result of standard docker operation as

```
 # sudo docker exec -it 7dde487b4424 pwd
```

Comment: Looks like the functionality is under the [IExecOperations](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/master/src/Docker.DotNet/Endpoints/IExecOperations.cs) class not IContainerOperations.  I assume it has to do with how the docker engine api is designed.  Might be worth reading the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Exec) on the exec feature as it's not as straight forward as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

You are only **creating** the exec instance but you are not **starting** it.  From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Exec):

> ## Exec
>
> Run new commands inside running containers. Refer to the
> [command-line reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) for more information.
>
> To exec a command in a container, **you first need to create an exec
> instance, *then start it***. These two API endpoints are wrapped up in a
> single command-line command, `docker exec`.

### Example Program

```
using Docker.DotNet;
using Docker.DotNet.Models;

namespace App
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: dotnet run <container-id-or-name> <commands...>");
        }

        public async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Usage();
                return;
            }

            await ExecAsync(args[0], args[1..^0]);
        }

        private static async Task ExecAsync(string imageIdOrName, string[] command)
        {
            DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(
                new Uri("unix:///var/run/docker.sock"))
                    .CreateClient();

            var execParams = new ContainerExecCreateParameters()
            {
                AttachStderr = true,
                AttachStdout = true,
                Cmd = command,
            };

            # Create the exec instance, it is not started yet.
            var exec = await client.Exec.ExecCreateContainerAsync(imageIdOrName, execParams);
            # Start the exec instance and capture the output stream.
            var stream = await client.Exec.StartAndAttachContainerExecAsync(exec.ID, false);
            await stream.CopyOutputToAsync(
                null,
                Console.OpenStandardOutput(),
                Console.OpenStandardError(),
                CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

### Example Program Output

```
# Create a running container
$ docker run --name docker-dotnet-test -d alpine tail -f
38a4dac4c5a2d42d57defbaa17778bb071a94e5a69c6427078ad278334fe5598
# Call our program with the container name and a command
$ dotnet run docker-dotnet-test echo hello world
hello world
```

### Notes

- I'm using the `StartAndAttachContainerExecAsync` method to capture stdout/stderr.  You can use `StartContainerExecAsync` if you don't care about the streams.

Comment: Thank you, @kthompso I don't have create NEW instance of container. I have list of container and I pass existing ContainerID to this program. I want to connect with additional BASH command to EXISTING working container instance. Creating new instances working fine in my project.

Comment: When you create the exec instance, it's not a new container -- it is a new instance of an execution of a command on an existing container -- but it (the command) has not yet been started.  You could think of creating the exec like typing in the bash command on your terminal and starting the exec as pressing the enter button.  If you look at the example I gave you, you will see that I am passing in the name of an existing container not creating a new one.  Please take care to read the answers carefully and take the time to review the official documentation.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, @kthompso, it'a a my mistake, I don't read your answer carefully, yes you working with existing container instance. Therefore I market you answer as solution. However (1) your code don't working in my project. I try to start it many times, one times I have received a couple line in output, but this is NOT result of my command PWD and LS -LA, this is something trash line from common docker log file.

Comment: (2) Any other attempt to start you solution get me error : 'Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"No such exec instance: 12"} in line StartAndAttachContainerExecAsync.

Comment: (3) You set up link to docker API documentation, docker API working perfectly in my project, I try to use Microsoft package Docker.DotNet and this package working worst, it don't has ANY documentation at all. And look as don't tested package at all (except with local windows docker).

Comment: Great, thank you for looking over the example and getting it running.  Could you post what you tried and what the output was?  I would make sure that you are using the correct docker URI, I hardcoded the location of the unix socket for execution against the local docker environment on linux.  If you are using a remote docker instance, or windows, you'll have to change that.  Also make sure you are using a valid image id or name for a running container.

Comment: Dear @kthompso, I use right container id without doubt (sudo docker ps), and my current program is huge, about 25,000 line of code. All parts of my current program with docker is working except of two main future - attach to container like ( # sudo docker exec -it 7dde487b4424 pwd ) and reading container log (# sudo docker logs 7dde487b4424) https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/issues/553 Current code fragment we speaking is https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/issues/554 I need only overcome two this issue to have opportunity to go ahead. But no, both of this future still don't working.

Comment: Dear @kthompso, Can you publish screen with result of you code? What you receive if you command is "pwd" and "ls -la"? Do you code is really working?